# echo next array value from sequence

Tags: php

So I have a file called `payout_dates.txt` and the file looks very similar to this;

```
01/01/17
01/02/17
01/03/17
...
```

Below I use the while function to go through each line of the document and display them as a select option what I'm trying to achieve is also display the text of the next line. for example I use`%1$s` to currently echo out the first result so I would need something like `%2$s` to echo the next result giving me a desired outcome like this;

```
 echo sprintf('  <option value="%1$s">%1$s to %2$s</option>'."\n", trim($dates));
```

resulting in the select option looking like `01/01/17 to 01/02/17`and so on and so on.

**my current code**

```
<?
    $payout_dates = fopen('/path/payout_dates.txt', 'r');
    while ($dates = fgets($payout_dates, 1024)) {
       echo sprintf('  <option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>'."\n", trim($dates));
    }
?>
```

Comment: In cases such as this you need to specify what to display on edge-cases (eg. if there's only 1 entry in the file or if there's an odd amount of entries in it - how do you want the last to display?)

Comment: @ccKep Yeah that would be an issue however in this case there is an even amount of entries :)

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: do not use PHP Short tags (`<?`) - these can be turned off and then your code is just shown as plain text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is not very big (will fit to RAM and still left RAM for further processing) than you can use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function.

```
$lines = file('/path/payout_dates.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line => $content) {
     $content = trim($content); // line will contain \r\n
     $next = isset($lines[$line+1]) ? trim($lines[$line+1]) : null;
     echo "<option value='{$content}'>from {$content}".(!empty($next) ? " to {$next}" : '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<?php
    $payout_dates = file('/path/payout_dates.txt');

    for($i = 0; $i < count($payout_dates) - 1; $i++)
    {
        $curDate = trim($payout_dates[$i]);
        $nextDate = trim($payout_dates[$i+1]);

        echo sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s to %2$s</option>'."\n", $curDate, $nextDate);
    }
```

Result:

```
<option value="01/01/17">01/01/17 to 01/02/17</option>
<option value="01/02/17">01/02/17 to 01/03/17</option>
<option value="01/03/17">01/03/17 to 01/04/17</option>
<option value="01/04/17">01/04/17 to 01/05/17</option>
```

Comment: what does it have to do with there being an even amount or odd amount of rows?

Comment: @Cashbee Nothing anymore, I had something else in mind - see the edit history ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to save the current value of $dates in a variable and echo it in the next iteration.

Note that this code will always echo one line less than there are lines in your file.

```
<?php
    $payout_dates = fopen('/path/payout_dates.txt', 'r');

    $lastDate = '';
    while ($dates = fgets($payout_dates, 1024)) {
        if($lastDate = ''){
            $lastDate = trim($dates);
        } else {
            $thisDate = trim($dates);
            echo sprintf('  <option value="%1$s">%1$s to %2$s</option>'."\n", $lastDate, $thisDate);
            $lastDate = $thisDate;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar with https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131113 but my, a bit more positive

```
<?php
    $payout_dates = fopen('payout_dates.txt', 'r');
    $preview = false;
    $html = '<select>';
    while ($dates = fgets($payout_dates, 1024)) {
        $html .= ($preview) 
            ? sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s to %2$s</option>'."\n", trim($preview),trim($dates))
            :'';
        $preview = $dates;
    }
    echo($html.'</select>');
?>
```

But https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131125/6390681 looks nicely.